# Most economical method to convert potassium oxide to potassium nitride.

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I have a compound potassium oxide($\ce{K2O}$) and I am trying to convert it into potassium nitride ($\ce{K3N}$).
Here are a few possible reaction methods :

- Split potassium oxide into the constituent elements potassium and oxygen  (Not very good  as a lot of energy is required)
- $\ce{K2O + N2 -> K3N + O2}$ (however this won't happen(?) because nitrogen has a lower electronegativity value than oxygen does)

and so on.

Does anyone know how can I convert the oxide to the nitride, releasing oxygen in the process, by not having to use a lot of energy-requiring processes?

Comment: The second reaction can happen- Thermodynamics are altered by concentration differential. Lots of Nitrogen and little K2O. It will need catalysing to break the nitrogen to atoms which is a kinetics problem. Potassium Nitride is not all that stable. Just look at Sodium Nitride in wikipedia.

Comment: @user2617804 How would I be best to begin on doing more research for the process that you mentioned above?

Comment: @user2617804 - Potassium nitride $\ce{K3N} \ne$ potassium azide $\ce{KN3}$

Answer (score 3):

Do you really want to go there?

Based on this entry from [Wikipedia](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6877/most-economical-method-to-convert-potassium-oxide-to-potassium-nitride) the compound is synthesized and stable only below room temperature, and on top of this requires elemental potassium:

> This compound was produced by the reaction of potassium metal and liquid nitrogen at 77 K (−196.2 °C; −321.1 °F) under vacuum:[[1](https://doi.org/10.1002/zaac.200300280)]
>
> $\ce{6K + N2 → 2K3N}$
>
> This compound decomposes back into potassium and nitrogen at room temperature.

You may want to check that the target is actually $\ce{K3N}$ versus the more plausible $\ce{KN3}$.

**Cited Reference**

1. Fischer, D.; Cancarevic, Z.; Schön, J. C.; Jansen, M. (January 2004). "Zur Synthese und Struktur von K3N". *Zeitschrift für anorganische und allgemeine Chemie* (in German). **630** (1): 156–160. https://doi.org/10.1002/zaac.200300280